# The use of function pathinfo() is discouraged Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, file-upload, coding-standards, file

I am checking uploaded file extension by pathinfo() function of php but in coding standard check it's shows

> The use of function pathinfo() is discouraged

My code:

```
$fileExt = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File` instead.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

class MyClass
{
   /**
    * @var File
    */
   private $file;

   /**
    * @param File $file
    */
   public function __construct(File $file)
   {
       $this->file = $file;
   }

   public function myMethod()
   {
       $path = 'this\is\some\dummy\path\potato.jpg';
       $pathInfo = $this->file->getPathInfo($path);
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` option as a second parameter however.

Comment: this will return an array, you can access the extension using key extension

Answer (score 0):

Use `\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory` for file operation
You can get file extension by this code:

```
$uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $scope]);
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
$uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

if ($uploader->save($this->getBaseDir())) {
    echo $fileName = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
    echo $fileExt = $uploader->getFileExtension();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the best way to achieve that, you'll get file extension from this code:

```
        $pathArray = explode('.', $path);
        $extension = end($pathArray);
        return $extension;
```